# Why does the .NET jupyter installation fail?

Tags: .net, .net-core, jupyter

I'm following [this tutorial](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-interactive-is-here-net-notebooks-preview-2/) to install .NET interactive.

```
> dotnet interactive jupyter install
You must install or update .NET to run this application.

App: C:\Users\rruiter\.dotnet\tools\dotnet-interactive.exe
Architecture: x64
Framework: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '7.0.0' (x64)
.NET location: C:\Program Files\dotnet\

The following frameworks were found:
  3.1.30 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  3.1.32 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  5.0.17 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  6.0.10 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  6.0.11 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  6.0.12 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  7.0.0-preview.5.22303.8 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]

Learn about framework resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed

To install missing framework, download:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.AspNetCore.App&framework_version=7.0.0&arch=x64&rid=win10-x64
```

I followed the link on the bottom, installed the framework, and after that ran `dotnet interactive jupyter install` again. It then failed again.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to install the [.NET 7.0 SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-7.0.102-windows-x64-installer) and not just the runtime.